# Bash Extract tar.gz file

Tags: bash, extract, tar, synology

I have my tar file under:

```
/volume1/@appstore/SynoDSApps/archiv/DE/2018_08_18__Lysto BackUp.tar.gz
```

With the tar command:

```
tar -tf "/volume1/@appstore/SynoDSApps/archiv/DE/2018_08_18__Lysto BackUp.tar.gz"
```

The command show me:

```
/volume1/02_public/3rd_Party_Apps/SPK_SCRIPTS/SynoDSApps/webapp/
/volume1/02_public/3rd_Party_Apps/SPK_SCRIPTS/SynoDSApps/webapp/exit_codes/
/volume1/02_public/3rd_Party_Apps/SPK_SCRIPTS/SynoDSApps/webapp/exit_codes/code_FUNC
/volume1/02_public/3rd_Party_Apps/SPK_SCRIPTS/SynoDSApps/webapp/exit_codes/code_SCRI
/volume1/02_public/3rd_Party_Apps/SPK_SCRIPTS/SynoDSApps/webapp/login/
/volume1/02_public/3rd_Party_Apps/SPK_SCRIPTS/SynoDSApps/webapp/login/check_appprivilege.php
/volume1/02_public/3rd_Party_Apps/SPK_SCRIPTS/SynoDSApps/webapp/login/check_login.php
/volume1/02_public/3rd_Party_Apps/SPK_SCRIPTS/SynoDSApps/webapp/login/privilege.php
/volume1/02_public/3rd_Party_Apps/SPK_SCRIPTS/SynoDSApps/webapp/scripte/
/volume1/02_public/3rd_Party_Apps/SPK_SCRIPTS/SynoDSApps/webapp/scripte/Lysto BackUp/
/volume1/02_public/3rd_Party_Apps/SPK_SCRIPTS/SynoDSApps/webapp/scripte/Lysto BackUp/sys
/volume1/02_public/3rd_Party_Apps/SPK_SCRIPTS/SynoDSApps/webapp/scripte/Lysto BackUp/sys_func
/volume1/02_public/3rd_Party_Apps/SPK_SCRIPTS/SynoDSApps/SSH_ERROR
```

My Plan or better my wish is to handle it like this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for PATHS in $(tar -tPf "/volume1/@appstore/SynoDSApps/archiv/DE/2018_08_18__Lysto BackUp.tar.gz")
do
    SED=$(echo "$PATHS" | sed 's/.*\///')
    if [[ -n "$SED" ]]
    then
        tar -C "${target_archiv}" -xvf "/volume1/@appstore/SynoDSApps/archiv/DE/2018_08_18__Lysto BackUp.tar.gz" "$PATHS"
        #echo JA
        echo "$PATHS"
    fi
done
unset IFS
```

i only want one file of the tar and Store this to a different Directory....
but this command with the -C don´t work... it Extract all the files of the tar....

My Question is, is it possible to extract only one file of the Tar without `cd` to the Directory ??
Another Question: is it possible to Extract only the files of the tar without the Folders this is maybe the better way but I don´t know how...?

and no I can not tar the files without the paths of it I need them...
so this is no way for me...

I hope for help here :)

Comment: The purpose of `-C` is exactly to `cd` to the directory, so you use the option but you don't want to `cd`? What did you think `-C` would do?

Comment: You don´t understand my Problem right.... this code: `tar -C "${target_archiv}" -xvf "/volume1/@appstore/SynoDSApps/archiv/DE/2018_08_18__Lysto BackUp.tar.gz" "$PATHS"` don´t work... because they Extract all of it.... but i only want one file....

Answer (score 0):

If your ultimate goal is to extract files without the full path, you can use a SED-like expression to rename the files while they are extracted, using the `--xform` option:

```
tar -C "${target_archiv}" -xvf "/volume1/@appstore/SynoDSApps/archiv/DE/2018_08_18__Lysto BackUp.tar.gz" --xform='s,^.*/,,'
```

The `'s,^.*/,,'` expression asks to substitute (`s`) from the beginning of the filename (`^`), capture everything (`.*`) and stop at the last slash (`/`) then replace it with nothing. In other words, it removes the directory structure from the filenames.

If you want to get rid of the empty folders that have been extracted, you may call this command after extracting:

```
find "${target_archiv}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Keep in mind it will remove all the (empty) subfolders of "${target_archiv}", even the ones that were already here before extracting the tarball. However, because `rmdir` will not remove directories that contain files, it will be mostly harmless to the subdirectories you had.

Comment: okay this is nice :) BUT tar gives me this output `/volume1/02_public/3rd_Party_Apps/SPK_SCRIPTS/SynoDSApps/webapp/` but this is a Directory.... and i don´t want to create Dir´s ...

Comment: Could you be more specific? Does it extract this directory only? Are files correctly extracted without tree structure, but you have this weird directory in the middle of it?

Comment: is it possible to Hide Folders like this: `webapp/` is the output of: '--show-transformed-names --xform='s,^.*/,,'` i don´t need all Folders: xxxx/.... do you know what i mean ??

Comment: I am not sure. Maybe you can try the `--exclude` option, something like `--exclude="^.*/$"` otherwise remove the folders *a posteriori*, e.g. call `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rmdir {} \;` after calling `tar`. WARNING it will remove all the (empty) directories you have right now, not only the ones that were extracted. Non-empty directories should be safe because `rmdir` will refuse to remove the directory if there are files inside it.

Comment: okay the finde commend works when i´m in the correct folder...... can i put in the find command the right Paths `"${target_archiv}"` all empty Folders in the Variable: `"${target_archiv}"`can be removed is this possible ??

Comment: You can tell `find` to start from the location you want if you put it after the command name and before the first option, e.g. `find "${target_archiv}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rmdir {} \;` I will edit the answer to add this command.